# Failing installation of Swirl in R

Tags: r, installation, swirl

Trying to install swirl but failed and following message appear in R console:

```
package ‘sys’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘assertthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘askpass’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'stringi/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Comment: have you tried: install.packages("swirl", dependencies = TRUE) or install.packages("stringi")?